# Create workflow within top level Private folder in plone 4.1

Tags: python, plone

I wish to create top level folders corresponding to different projects. Each project folder is private to a user group i.e when the user logs in, he can view the contents of his folder only. There should not be any workflow associated for this project folder.i.e the state of this folder should remain 'Private' all the time. Further within this folder I need to have custom workflow by defining a workflow policy, or use the default workflow of the site to work. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is w.r.t https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497735/multiple-project-folders-with-workflows-plone-4-1 which has been closed. Just re-edited the post.I have come across a solution that works for me. Thought of sharing it with those facing a similar challenge,and also with you https://stackoverflow.com/users/835961/sdupton for your efforts to reply for my ticket:
IMPORTANT: To make top level folders private only all the time, we can define a custom workflow with only 1 state: Private
You can use the ZMI, select Contents/ portal_workflow/ then the tab contents and copy & paste the intranet_workflow for folders. Rename it to the private_workflow. Then for the states of the private_workflow, keep only the private state and delete all the transitions and other states for the workflow. Select the content type folder and apply the custom private_workflow to it.
For the sub-folders continue the workflow assigned to them using the workflow policies.